Chunking text with bounding box values
I have used the Azure OCR service to extract text from PDFs. For each page in a PDF, the OCR output contains a list of text lines along with the bounding box values for that line. My original approach to chunk the text in each page was to firstly combine the strings in the list of texts using "\n" and use the RecursiveCharacterTextSplitter() from Langchain. However, I am not able to store the bounding box values for each chunk using this approach.
For each chunk, I want to be able to store the boundingbox value of the first and last line in the chunk. This is to ensure that I can later highlight the particular chunk in the PDF using the chunk's bounding box values.
I am now currently using a different chunking strategy where I iterate through each line in a page and keep track of the character count and once it reaches a particular character limit, I add text from those set of lines into a new chunk and start the process all over again with the next of chunks. This is my code to do the same :
for line in item['lines']:
    character_count += len(line['text'])
    cumulative_lines.append(line)
    if character_count >= character_limit:
        chunk_start_bbox = cumulative_lines[0]['boundingBox']
        chunk_end_bbox = cumulative_lines[-1]['boundingBox']
        chunk_text = "\n".join(line['text'] for line in cumulative_lines)
        chunk_metadata = metadata_dict.copy()
        chunk_metadata.update({'chunk_start_bbox': chunk_start_bbox, 'chunk_end_bbox': chunk_end_bbox})
        chunk_docs.append(Document(page_content=chunk_text, metadata=metadata_dict))
        character_count = 0
        cumulative_lines = []

However, I feel this is a very inefficient solution, going through each line in a page. Moreover, I also wouldn't consider the overlap of characters in a chunk, like how Langchain does.
Can someone suggest a better way to achieve this? Also, is there a way I can make my code more performant?
